# This program is supposed to ask you a link, which is converted to an qrcode for some reason some things in the code are not working

Tags: python, tkinter, qr-code

This program is supposed to ask the user for an input that will be later used to create a QR code.  There's a button, which isn't working, that is supposed to create that QR code.  After that, there is another button that is supposed to open that QR code as an image.

For some reason I can't understand how I am going to use the input the user gives.  Also, the QR code is generated before I even do anything.

```py
import qrcode 
import tkinter
from PIL import Image



main = tkinter.Tk("Link converter to QrCode ")
main.title("Link converter to Qr Code")
main.geometry("685x85")

#This is used just for what the person should write on the side
link = tkinter.Label(
    main, 
    width="30",
    text=('Link:'))
link.grid(row=0)

#this entry is supposed to receive an input that will later be used
e1 = tkinter.Entry(
    main, 
    bd="5", 
    width="75",
    text=(""))
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

#This is what should be getting the input from above
def retrieve_input():
    input = main.e1.get("1.0")
x=input



#This button is supposed to create the qrcode with the input given above
button_create = tkinter.Button(
    main, 
    text="Click to create the Qrcode.", 
    command = lambda: qrcode.make(x))
button_create.grid(row=2, column=1)

img = qrcode.make()
img.save ("Qrcode.png")



#This button should open the image of the qrcode
button_open = tkinter.Button ( 
    main,  
    text="Click here to open the Qrcode", 
    command = lambda: Image.open(open("Qrcode.png", "rb")),
    width="25")
button_open.grid(row=2, column=0)


#This button is working and is just to close the program
exit_button = tkinter.Button(
    main,
    width=("15"),
    text='Exit',
    command= lambda: main.quit())
exit_button.grid(row=3, column=0)


main.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am new to coding so if someone nows how to make this work, try to explain it  in a simple way.

Comment: i already fixed my open button i changed from open. to show. which fixed

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the entry and use it as the argument to `qrcode.make()`.

Put this code into the `retrieve_input()` function, and call that from the button.

```
#This is what should be getting the input from above
def retrieve_input():
    img = qrcode.make(e1.get())
    img.save("Qrcode.png")

#This button is supposed to create the qrcode with the input given above
button_create = tkinter.Button(
    main,
    text="Click to create the Qrcode.",
    command = retrieve_input)
button_create.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Comment: I still cant use the input the user gives me to create an qrcode it creates an qrcode with nothing inside

Comment: Do you see the entered text if you change it to `lambda: print(e1.get())`?

Comment: what do you mean by i can see?

Comment: That should print the contents of the text entry on the terminal when you click the button. Do you see what you entered in the text box?

Comment: Nothing happers in the terminal

Comment: What if you change it to `command = lambda: print("You clicked the create button")`? Do you see that message?

Comment: its like blank lines just appear

Comment: yes when i do that it says You clicked the create button

Comment: I've updated the answer, try this.

Comment: right now i am able to print the e1.get when i write something and then  i click the button it show im my terminal